# Get substring from pandas dataframe while filtering

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe with the following information:

```
Name    Points          String
John        24     FTS8500001A
Richard     35     FTS6700001B
John        29     FTS2500001A
Richard     35     FTS3800001B
John        34     FTS4500001A
```

Here is the way to get a DataFrame with the sample above:

```
import pandas as pd
keys = ('Name', 'Points', 'String')
names = pd.Series(('John', 'Richard', 'John', 'Richard', 'John'))
ages = pd.Series((24,35,29,35,34))
strings = pd.Series(('FTS8500001A','FTS6700001B','FTS2500001A','FTS3800001B','FTS4500001A'))
df = pd.concat((names, ages, strings), axis=1, keys=keys)
```

I want to select every row that meet the following criteria: Name=Richard And Points=35. And for such rows I want to read the 4th and 5th char of the String column (the two numbers just after FTS).

**The output I want is the numbers 67 and 38.**

I’ve tried several ways to achieve it but with zero results. Can you please help?

Thank you very much.
Eduardo

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a boolean mask to filter your df and then call [`str`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling) and slice the string:

```
In [77]:
df.loc[(df['Name'] == 'Richard') & (df['Points']==35),'String'].str[3:5]

Out[77]:
1    67
3    38
Name: String, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks again Ed.  The `.str` was a plus!

Answer (score 7):

## Pandas string methods

You can mask it on your criteria and then use [pandas string methods](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling)

```
mask_richard = df.Name == 'Richard'
mask_points = df.Points == 35
df[mask_richard & mask_points].String.str[3:5]

1    67
3    38
```

Comment: Thanks for the link and for this new concept of doing the query!